# find marks of each student for each quarter.write a query to find out the maximum mark of all the quarters for each student

Tags: sql, oracle

find the mathematics marks of each student for each quarter.  We need to write a query to find out the maximum mark  of all the quarters for each student

Sample Table.

```
STUDENT NAME    Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4     
AAA             80  60  65  50     
BBB             71  75  70  55     
CCC             70  80  90  56     
DDD             45  55  65  90
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has the `least()` and `greatest()` functions:

```
select student, greatest(q1, q2, q3, q4) as greatest_value
from sample;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    ( STUDENTNAME  varchar(3),  Q1  int,  Q2  int,  Q3  int,  Q4  int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    ( STUDENTNAME ,  Q1 ,  Q2 ,  Q3 ,  Q4 )
VALUES
    ('AAA', 80, 60, 65, 50),
    ('BBB', 71, 75, 70, 55),
    ('CCC', 70, 80, 90, 56),
    ('DDD', 45, 55, 65, 90)
;

Select T.STUDENTNAME,MAX(T.val)[Quarter] from (
select STUDENTNAME,col,val from @Table1
CROSS APPLY (values ('Q1',q1),
('Q2',q2),
('Q3',q3),
('Q4',q4))cs(col,val))T
GROUP BY T.STUDENTNAME
```